# How do I find last index of true value in a dataframe when applying condition to each row in an efficient way in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us say I have pandas dataframe having two columns, *previous* and *current*. We can assume that values are non-decreasing and *current* values are always greater than *previous* value.

Now, for each element in *previous* column, I want to look up index of last value of *current* column which is less than this value. I then want to subtract that index from the this element's index and store that value in the new column, say *numIndexes*

working but inefficient code is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'previous': [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,17],'current': [2,6,9,10,15,19,20,21]})
df['numIndexes']=1
for i in range(len(df)):
    x=df['previous'][i]>df['current']
    df['numIndexes'][i]=i-x[::-1].idxmax()

OUTPUT
    previous    current numIndexes
0   1   2   -7
1   3   6   1
2   5   9   2
3   7   10  2
4   9   15  3
5   11  19  2
6   13  20  3
7   17  21  3
```

Ignore the first negative value.

To explain my objective via example above, for 5th index, we have previous value as 11. Now in the current column, last index where current value is less than 11 is index 3. This gives me numIndexes for 5th row as 2 ( 5-3)

For a large dataset, this method is extremely slow. Any help appreciated to speed up this logic.

EDIT : The assumption of strictly increasing values is not correct. Values are non-decreasing. However, each previous value is strictly less than its corresponding current value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the values are non-decreasing, you can use numpy.broadcasting, `[:, None]`, to compare the current values with all previous values. We then take the sum and subtract 1 since counting starts at 0, giving us the index position of the last row with current value < the previous value for all rows in the DataFrame.

Then create your column, which is the index minus the index of this calculated row.

```
ilocs = (df['current'].to_numpy()[:, None] < df['previous'].to_numpy()).sum(0) - 1
df['numIndexes'] = df.index  - df.index[ilocs]

   previous  current  numIndexes
0         1        2          -7
1         3        6           1
2         5        9           2
3         7       10           2
4         9       15           3
5        11       19           2
6        13       20           3
7        17       21           3
```

---

The above is memory intensive. If that doesn't work you can use an `asof` merge to match on the last row with the current value < previous value. We bring along the index so you can then perform the subtraction afterwards. I've left the additional columns showing the value it matched and the index it matched in for illustration -- drop them if you don't care.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.merge_asof(df, df[['current']].reset_index(),
                   left_on='previous', right_on='current',
                   suffixes=['', '_match'],
                   allow_exact_matches=False  # Require strictly less than
                  )

df['numIndexes'] = df.index - df['index']

   previous  current  index  current_match  numIndexes
0         1        2    NaN            NaN         NaN
1         3        6    0.0            2.0         1.0
2         5        9    0.0            2.0         2.0
3         7       10    1.0            6.0         2.0
4         9       15    1.0            6.0         3.0
5        11       19    3.0           10.0         2.0
6        13       20    3.0           10.0         3.0
7        17       21    4.0           15.0         3.0
```

Comment: Assumption of strictly increasing is not true. Values are non-decreasing. I have made the edit in the original question as well. This method is blowing up memory requirement.

Comment: @lonstud See my update, try the `asof` merge solution, it should be a lot more memory friendly and should still vastly outperform your loop.

Comment: Thank you @ALollz. This works very well and is lightning quick. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the `subtract.outer`, with `argmax`

```
df.index - np.cumsum(np.subtract.outer(df['previous'].values,df['current'].values),axis=1).argmax(axis=1)
Out[278]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: The assumption of strictly increasing is not true. The values are non-decreasing. I have made the edit in the original question. This method is blowing up memory way too much even for a smaller dataset.